# Subir varios clientes a un API con PHP

Tags: php, api, post

Buen día, tengo un problema en cuanto intento subir personas a un API de pruebas, enviando una persona por Postman se demora alrededor de 1ms en devolverme la respuesta del servidor. Pero quiero enviar varias personas ya que eso es lo que se espera, creé un script en PHP pero el problema es que para devolverme la respuesta se demora al rededor de 5 minutos, incluso si envío una sola persona (significa que no es por la cantidad de personas enviadas).

Esta es la función que creé:

```
public function sendRequest($requestData) {

    $responses = [];

    // Dividir en lotes más pequeños para un mejor rendimiento
    $lotesClientes = array_chunk($requestData, 10);

    foreach ($lotesClientes as $lote) {
        $curlHandles = [];
        $curlMultiHandle = curl_multi_init();

        foreach ($lote as $cliente) {
            $curl = curl_init();

            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $this->apiUrl,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_POST => true,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($cliente),
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    'Authorization: ' . $this->apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                ),
            ));

            curl_multi_add_handle($curlMultiHandle, $curl);
            $curlHandles[] = $curl;
        }

        $running = null;
        do {
            curl_multi_exec($curlMultiHandle, $running);
        } while ($running > 0);

        foreach ($curlHandles as $curl) {
            $response = curl_multi_getcontent($curl);
            $httpStatusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            $responses[] = array(
                'status_code' => $httpStatusCode,
                'response' => $response
            );
            curl_multi_remove_handle($curlMultiHandle, $curl);
            curl_close($curl);
        }

        curl_multi_close($curlMultiHandle);
    }

    return $responses;

}
```

En RequestData es todo un array de varias personas

Comment: Hola. ¿Para qué es este código exactamente y por qué usas cURL multi? ¿Cuando hablas de *subir varias personas* a qué te refieres?

Comment: Se refiere a importar varios contactos. Por ejemplo el API de MailChimp te hace cargarlos de a uno